# Need to change the dimentions in order to calculate equation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, physics

Input

```
def Gaussan_wave_packet():

    quantum_number = 500
    x = np.linspace(0,100,1000).astype(complex).reshape(1000,1)
    n = np.arange(1,quantum_number+1).reshape(1,500)
    x0 = 50, a = 5, l = 1, m = 0.511*10**6, L = x[-1], hbar = 6.58211951*10**(-16)
    A = (1/(4*a**2))**(1/4.0)

    psi_x0 = (np.exp((-(x - x0)**2)/(4*a**2))*np.exp(1j*l*x)).reshape(len(x),1)

    A = ( 1/(np.sqrt(np.trapz((np.conj(psi_x0[:,0])*psi_x0[:,0]), x[:,0]))))
        psi_x0_normalized = A*psi_x0[:,0].reshape(1000,1) #(1000,1)

    phi = ( np.sqrt( 2/L ) * np.sin( (n*x*np.pi) /L ) )  #(1000,500)

    En = ( ( np.power(n,2))*(np.pi**2)*(hbar**2))/(2*m*L**2) #(1,500)

    Cn = np.trapz( ( np.conj(phi)*psi_x0_normalized[:,0] ), x[:,0] )
```

Output

```
Scalar A: (0.28246850458110645+0j)
Psi0 Normalized: (1000, 1)
Phi: (1000, 500)
En: (1, 500)
/Gaussan_wave_packet", line 48, in Gaussan_wave_packet
Cn = np.trapz( ( np.conj(phi)*psi_x0_normalized[:,0] ), x[:,0] )# Needs to be (1,500)
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1000,500) (1000,)
```

### Thoughts

I'm not sure what is going wrong here. All of my variables seem to have the correct dimensions and appropriate values. As shown in the output, the shapes are correct and so are the values. I'm moving over from programming problems in MATLAB to python and I'm not really sure where this value (1000,) is coming from, for it is very different from matlab. Am I not indexing right, element-wise multiplication, or do I need a for loop. I'm not sure where to go about this. I need Cn to be shape (1,500).

Comment: Try with `np.conj(phi).T.dot(psi_x0_normalized[:,0] ))`

Comment: Returned this error: ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (999,) (499,)

Comment: Then it must be when integrating, try `np.trapz( ( np.conj(phi)*psi_x0_normalized[:,0] ).T, x[:,0] )`

Comment: There are subtle differences in indexing. `X[:, 0]` for a 1000x1 `X` will give you a **1D** array in Python whereas in matlab I believe it should essentially give you back `X`. What happens if you omit the `[:, 0]`?

Comment: Unfortunately, still not working. I wonder if I for loop through np.conj(phi)*psi_x0_normalized[:,0] and then integrate if it will work.

Comment: If I omit [:,0] it returns ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1000,0) (1000,499)

Comment: In that case you could try `[:, 0, None]` this should work, though the result being empty might not be that interesting.

Comment: Figured it out! I'll post an answer in a bit in case anyone else comes across this problem. Once I broke it down a little bit I was able to figure out what was happening. I created a new variable (random name) Q. `Q = (np.conj(phi)*psi_x0_normalized)`, then found the shape `print("Q: " + str(Q.shape))`. It became apparent to what I had to do next. I created a for loop as such, `    for i in range(0,quantum_number):
        Cn[i] = np.trapz( Q[:,i], x[:,0] )# Needs to be (1,500)`. Then I just reshaped `Cn = Cn.reshape(1,500)`, I ended with the correct size and values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array index had to be applied after both phi and psi_x0_normalized were multiplied together. I also used a for loop to get Cn to the correct shape and reshaped it to a vector with multiple columns as desired.

```
Q = np.zeros((quantum_number,1))
Cn = np.zeros((quantum_number,1))

Q = (np.conj(phi)*psi_x0_normalized)

print("Q: " + str(Q.shape))
#print("Q: " + str(Q))
for i in range(0,quantum_number):
    Cn[i] = np.trapz( Q[:,i], x[:,0] )# Needs to be (1,500)

Cn = Cn.reshape(1,500)
print("Cn: " + str(Cn.shape))
```